# Date Of Birth + Birthday SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a requirement to store the users DOB. I have created a form on the front end to take in their DOB `year`, `month` and `day` via 3 select drop downs. I am currently storing these three values in SQL with columns of the same name.

One of the queries I need to perform is to get all users above or below a certain age. I am new to SQL and can't think of the proper way to do this with the current way I am storing data. At first I thought I'd just store the name in the same column but quickly realized that after a full year every single row would be incorrect.

So my question is how should I store this data to perform a query that can find users within a particular age range? Thanks!

Comment: What are the current data types of the year/month/day columns? integers? strings? leading zeros or no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you store the `DOB` in a single column of data type `date` you can query it like this

```
select * from your_table
where DOB <= curdate() - interval 18 year
and   DOB >= curdate() - interval 35 year
```

to get users between 18 and 35 years old.

The  `DOB` should be a `date` - so `YYYY-MM-DD` for instance `1980-12-31`

Comment: How exactly should DOB look when going into the DB?

Comment: How can I get between age x and y?

Answer (score 1):

If possible, I would suggest storing date of birth as DATE type.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
name VARCHAR(128),
dob  DATE );
```

then the query is very easy:

```
SELECT name, dob FROM users WHERE dob <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 18 YEARS;
```

(to select all users who are older than 18)

If you really want to do it with year, month, date stored separately, and you want this query to perform, you can do it:

```
SELECT name, STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS(',',year,month,day),"%Y-%m-%d")
FROM users
WHERE year<=YEAR(CURDATE())-18 
AND month<=MONTH(CURDATE()) AND day<=DAY(CURDATE());
```

provided that you have the following index:

```
ALTER TABLE users
ADD index dob_idx(year, month, date);
```

(otherwise it will not be running fast when there'll be many rows).